# How to add a property page to DirectShow filter

Tags: com, directshow

I have written an DirectShow-Filter *.ax to integrate a Hardware (Camera). All works fine with my filter.ax and there Transport Images to Skype success.

Now I am want to integrate a Dialog to handle the camera-options with UI.

In my Filter.ax is calling the function `QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)`

when `riid ==  IID_ISpecifyPropertyPages`

I am have seen that the Dialog must be in a other DLL like Com ?

My try to open the Dialog directly works, but no windows Messages are incoming.

I must also write an MFC Dll they is starting by PropertyPage IIID ? My Propertypage is a large MFC Controles TabControl with some items. I can see it if i start the filter from MFC Test app. AfxInit I can't execute. (Wrong Lib versions I must use the directshow baseclass(knowledge example)

I don't now why my Dialog got no Messages, what is the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement a property page in a separate DLL (even though it is a possible).

DirectShow filter property pages are regular COM property pages implemented using `ISpecifyPropertyPages`. Property pages are separate COM objects implementing well known interfaces like `IPropertyPage`.

Windows SDK [Ezrgb24 sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375634) shows how to implement a simple transform filter and also features a property page ([`CEZrgb24Properties` class](https://github.com/lgtkgtv/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/multimedia/directshow/filters/ezrgb24/ezprop.h#L11)). It should be a good start for a property page implementation for your filter.

If you prefer to implement the property page in a separate DLL, a typical way is to define a shared COM interface, the filter would implement it and reference the property page by its CLSID, the property page would query this interface from the filter instance and use it for configuration actions.